# Why is result of filter with count not usable directly as conditional in Swift 3

Tags: swift

Noob here.

Why is this ok:

```
let lockedCount = myStructArray.filter{$0.isLocked == true}.count
```

and this not ok:

```
if myStructArray.filter{$0.isLocked == true}.count < 4 {
    print("Fewer than 4 locked")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has trouble parsing anonymous closure in the context of an `if` logical expression. You can work around this issue by parenthesizing the `count` expression:

```
if (myStructArray.filter{$0.isLocked == true}.count) < 4 {
// ^                                               ^
    print("Fewer than 4 locked")
}
```

or

```
if (myStructArray.filter{$0.isLocked == true}.count < 4) {
// ^                                                   ^
    print("Fewer than 4 locked")
}
```

or

```
if myStructArray.filter({$0.isLocked == true}).count < 4 {
//                     ^                     ^
    print("Fewer than 4 locked")
}
```

Comment: Not really, OP is missing the parenthesis around the filter: this works fine `if myStructArray.filter({ $0.isLocked == true }).count < 4`

Comment: @RashwanL There's more than one way to help Swift figure out this parse. You can also put parentheses around the entire condition.