# Is this a Swift compiler bug, or a feature? .filter appears to have issues

Tags: swift, filter

I think I have encountered a Swift Bug but would like to check here before opening a case for it.  The bug appears to be related to the filter function returning a boolean before the full value is calculated.

I have no way to test older versions now, but I am fairly certain this worked fine in previous versions of Swift.

It might also be due to .filter now including a "throws" and "rethrows" clause.

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Element]
```

**Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001) and Swift 5.1**

Below are several iterations of the problem, but the key issue is line 15, which won't compile unless I add "spurious" parentheses around the left half of the conditional (as per line 12).

Line 12 works fine but doesn't display correctly in the playground.  It is relevant to note that the "false" displayed, is the result of the final iteration of the closure (the same as in line 5), and that the print gets called, but you can't see the output.  If the if-statement is changed to multiple lines, you can see the result of the print.

I moved the code to a playground from a project to simplify it, and noticed a lot of strange playground behavior due to the issue, as noted in the comments.

Here is the code in a playground:

[image: Playground Results and Errors]

Here is the text version:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,0]

//This won't show the value of b in the playground
//It only shows the result of the closure on the last iteration through arr
let b = arr.filter{$0>2}
//This works fine, and we get the display
let d = b
//This works fine
if b.count > 2 { print("Multiple") } else { print("One") }

//This doesn't show the output in a playground
if (arr.filter{$0>2}.count) > 1 { print("Multiple") } else { print("One") }

//This won't compile, having only removed the "spurious" parentheses above
if arr.filter{$0>2}.count > 1 { print("Multiple") } else { print("One") }
```

Comment: `if arr.filter({$0>2}).count > 1 { print("Multiple") } else { print("One") `. Always use the function parentheses when used in an expression with other curly braces like an `if`.

Comment: That is a known issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604331/why-is-result-of-filter-with-count-not-usable-directly-as-conditional-in-swift-3 and the linked questions.